# LinkedIn OAuth a required parameter "client_id" is missing

Tags: php, json, curl, linkedin-api

I am working with the LinkedIn API and trying to make request but when I try to get my accesstoken I am getting the following error in my json print:

```
Array ( [error] => missing_parameter [error_description] => A required parameter "client_id" is missing )
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

    $url = parse_url("https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
    parse_str($url['query'], $url);
        
    $code = $url['code'];

    $data = array("grant_type" => "authorization_code", 
                  "code" => $code,
                  "redirect_uri" => "REDIRECT_URI",
                  "client_id" => "SECRET",
                  "client_secret" => "SECRET"
              );
                
    $url2 = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
        
    $result_array = json_decode($result, true);

    print_r($result_array);
        
    include('../twitter/navigatie.php');

    echo '<div class="container">';
    
    echo '';

    echo '</div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem

it needed to be in a string.

so this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

became this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Curl or LinkedIn seemed kinda sensitive for it.

Comment: this help so much