# LinkedIn oauth error A required parameter "client_id" is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, linkedin-api

so I am just upgrading from LinkedIn oauth 1.0 to 2.0 and I have been getting this error for about a day now. I saw a post about it for php but I cannot figure it out in Node JS (Javascript) here is my current code :

```
axios
    .post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: req.query.code,
      redirect_uri: keys.linkedinCallbackURL,
      client_id: keys.linkedinConsumerKey,
      client_secret: keys.linkedinConsumerSecret
    })
    .then(res2 => {
      console.log(res2);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

If you have any ideas let me know :)

Link to php solution: [LinkedIn OAuth a required parameter "clien_id" is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369757/linkedin-oauth-a-required-parameter-clien-id-is-missing)

Link to LinkedIn guide: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2
(error occurring on step 3)

Comment: what value are you submitting for clien_id (i.e. what is 'keys.linkedinConsumerKey')?

Comment: keys.linkedinConsumerKey is the app id given by linkedin. LinkedinConsumerKey is a poor variable name.

Comment: your error seems to be telling you that the clien_id is not getting passed. Try to catch what value are you passing?

Comment: In the consloe.log(error); I can see what the request and client_id is passed in with the correct variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The LinkedIn documentation ask you to send the data as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and they show us this exemple:

```
POST /oauth/v2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.linkedin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code=987654321&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myapp.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&client_id=123456789&client_secret=shhdonottell
```

The [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) says that by default the body is serialized as JSON:

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON.

In order to serialize the body properly you should use the `querystring` module as following:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

axios
    .post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", querystring.stringify({
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: req.query.code,
      redirect_uri: keys.linkedinCallbackURL,
      client_id: keys.linkedinConsumerKey,
      client_secret: keys.linkedinConsumerSecret
    }));
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks :)

Comment: from where Code: value come ? @yannick-loriot