# Spring Boot 3.0 OAuth2 Linkedin [invalid_request] A required parameter "client_secret" is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-social-linkedin

I'm trying to integrate Google and LinkedIn Social Login using OAuth2 in Spring Boot 3.0. Google login is working fine but I'm encountering an error with LinkedIn login.

Here is my configuration:

```yaml
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-id=xxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-secret=xxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/linkedin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.scope[0]=r_emailaddress
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.scope[1]=r_liteprofile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.authorization-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.token-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.user-info-uri=https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
```

I've also included my debug log below:

[image]

this is the error :
[image]

Comment: Is your case like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328716/3728901?